# MYSQL query with left join

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query and I would like to add one paramenter more. The query relates to Woocommerce Products. I need only products, which are in_stock. So the original query looks like this:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT `post_author`, `guid`, `post_status`, `post_type`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `user_id`, `user_nicename`, count(*) FROM `3XvmI7jKh0_posts` as p left join `3XvmI7jKh0_usermeta` as um on um.user_id = p.post_author left join `3XvmI7jKh0_users` as un on un.ID = p.post_author where um.meta_key = 'sow_vendor_geocoding' and p.post_status = 'publish' and p.post_type = 'product'  GROUP BY `post_author`")or die(mysql_error());
```

My last try was like this, however it does generate an error. What I'm doing wrong?

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT `post_author`, `guid`, `post_status`, `post_type`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `user_id`, `user_nicename`, count(*) FROM `3XvmI7jKh0_posts` as p left join `3XvmI7jKh0_usermeta` as um on um.user_id = p.post_author left join `3XvmI7jKh0_users` as un on un.ID = p.post_author left join `3XvmI7jKh0_postmeta` as ur on ur.post.id = p.id where um.meta_key = 'sow_vendor_geocoding' and p.post_status = 'publish' and p.post_type = 'product' and ur.meta_value = "in_stock" GROUP BY `post_author`")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please stop using PHP's ancient, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the quotes unitentionally:

```
"SELECT a FROM foo WHERE b = "bar";"
```

Instead you either want to escape the double quotes or copy the other clauses and use single quotes:

```
"SELECT a FROM foo WHERE b = 'bar';"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using double quotes within the query, which itself is bound by double quotes. You need to escape the quotes around `"in_stock"` (`\"in_stock\"`), or replace them with single quotes `'`